# How to define and play sound effects within the class

Tags: python, pygame

This is a the class of a sprite that goes left and right on the screen, when it hits the boundaries, it makes a "boing" sound and goes the opposite direction, everything works perfectly fine except for there is no boing sound when it hits the edge

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("vegetables.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 167
        self.__direction = 10


    def update(self):
        self.rect.left += self.__direction
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Bounce.mp3")
        sound.set_volume(0.5)
        if (self.rect.left < 0) or (self.rect.right > screen.get_width()):          
            sound.play()
            self.__direction = -self.__direction
```

Comment: You say there is a boing sound and then you say there isn’t? Please be more specific about the sequence of things that’s happening. Does the sound happen once but not after that? Does it happen consistently for some edges but not others?

Comment: For starters, load the sound in `__init__` rather than loading it every frame in `update`.

Comment: @bdesham what i meant is that the boing was supposed to happen, but it is not working and there is no boing right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the class to play its own sound, just load it like any attribute on `__init__`.

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("vegetables.gif")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("Bounce.mp3")   #like this
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.left = 0
        self.rect.top = 167
        self.__direction = 10
```

Then whenever it's correct to do so, just call `self.sound.play()`.

```
  def update(self):
        self.rect.left += self.__direction
        if (self.rect.left < 0) or (self.rect.right > screen.get_width()):          
            self.sound.play()                    #as seen here
            self.__direction = -self.__direction
```

For whatever it's worth - if you're going to do it in this way (have the sprite play its own sounds, etc), I would recommend loading them beforehand and then passing them as arguments (perhaps default arguments to avoid errors), such that each instance of the class might call a unique sound if need be.

So in your code **prior** to these classes, one could do something like:

```
JumpSound = pygame.Mixer.Sound("jump.wav")
BonkSound = pygame.Mixer.Sound("bonk.wav")
#etc etc etc...
```

...and then later on, pass the sounds as arguments:

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, jumpsound, bonksound):
        #...your other code precedes...
        self.jumpsound = jumpsound
        self.bonksound = bonksound
        #...your other code continues...

myHero = MySprite(JumpSound, BonkSound)
```

The names are a little bit lousy b/c they are the same barring the CamelCasing, but forgetting that, this is probably a much cleaner approach. You can set your volume on the sounds way before they are passed into the sprites, along with whatever other changes you feel are necessary before the sprite gets ahold of them.

Comment: but it gives an error... AttributeError: 'MySprite' object has no attribute 'sound'

Comment: Maybe post the current state of your code in an edit to the OP? Maybe there is another kind of error